# What is the simple way to create duplicates of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame which has 5 rows of data. I want to make 4 duplicate set of same data frame.

Input

```
col1    col2
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
e   5
```

Output:

```
col1    col2
a      1
b      2
c      3
d      4
e      5
a      1
b      2
c      3
d      4
e      5
a      1
b      2
c      3
d      4
e      5
a      1
b      2
c      3
d      4   
e      5
```

for example in python if i have a string `s='-'` to make duplicate I could do something like this `print s*4`. I want similar functionality in pandas.

So far I tried `pd.concat`

`df=pd.concat([df,df,df,df])`

But the problem is Some times i have to create more than 20 duplicates dataframes. Is there any other way to make duplicate dataframes in pythonic way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `concat` one dataframe in list with multiple by repeats:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 3, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     a     1
1     b     2
2     c     3
3     d     4
4     e     5
5     a     1
6     b     2
7     c     3
8     d     4
9     e     5
10    a     1
11    b     2
12    c     3
13    d     4
14    e     5
```

Another solution with repeat index values [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and expand by `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[np.tile(df.index, 3)].reset_index(drop=True)
```